# scala: find method on a tree with Optional return type

Tags: scala

I am writing a find method on a tree like structure. This is my code:

```
def find[T](node: Node, findThisGuy: T): Option[Node] = {
    if (node.data == findThisGuy) {
        Some(node)
    } else {
        if (node.children.nonEmpty) {
            node.children.foreach(child => {
                find(child, findThisGuy)
            })
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Issue at hand here is the inner if has return type of `Unit` which does conform to function's return type i.e. `Option[Node]`. So how do I define the return type of inner `if`? I am open for suggestions on better implementation of above method.

Comment: What is your desired behavior?  Do you want it to return a `Some(node)` from the first child that doesn't return `None` for the recursive call?

Answer (score 2):

I think this will do the trick:

```
def find[T](node: Node, findThisGuy: T): Option[Node] = {
  if (node.data == findThisGuy) {
    Some(node)
  } else {
    node.children.view
      .map(child => find(child, findThisGuy))
      .collectFirst{case Some(guy) => guy}
  }
}
```

Comment: Note that this will not stop searching once it has found the correct node, it will go through the whole tree. You could use `children.find(child => find(child, findThisGuy).isDefined)` instead, which will (and also saves you the `.collectFirst` call).

Comment: Yes, you are right, just edited it. I wanted to put a `.view` before the `.map`, which would make it lazy, but I forgot. Anyway, good point with the `.find`.

Comment: You could also just call `collectFirst` straightaway: `node.children.collectFirst(Function.unlift(find(_, findThisGuy)))`

Comment: Well, you should go with `node.children.view.map(find(_, findThisGuy)).find(_.isDefined).flatten`. You current code that uses `find` will return immediate child of current node instead of result of recursive call.

Comment: You are right. I will revert the code and add the `.view`. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, I usually prefer to avoid using `collectFirst`, because it's default implementation in `TraversableOnce` uses `return` which is implemented in scala by throwing control exceptions. So, basically, its performance sucks.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are not using the return of the self call to `find`. You should use a standard for:

```
def find[T](node: Node, findThisGuy: T): Option[Node] = {
  if (node.data == findThisGuy)
    return Some(node)

  for (c <- node.children) {
    val found = find(c, findThisGuy)
    if (found.isDefined)
      return found
  }
  None
}
```

Note that there is no need to ask for `if (node.children.nonEmpty)` if you are traversing the array later. An empty traversal just does nothing.

Also, this might look less functional, but has the advantage that it stops searching as soon as it finds the node, instead of evaluating ALL children. A common pitfall IMHO.